# "Tagging" tags (so to speak)

Tags: discussion, tagging

With over 1,500 tags ([SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) shows 1.3k, and for Mathematics, with 360k questions, 1.1k tags) I find it difficult to know what tags (if any!) to add to a post tagged with only one or two of these and certainly have no feel for which suit best (eg [formula-one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formula-one) and/or [grand-prix](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-prix)?)

I would expect continued significant growth (relative to some other SE sites) in their numbers due to TSE’s nature. For reference purposes, it might be helpful to classify these tags in some way additional to popular, name and new. There may be some discernible themes, perhaps:

Activity
Airline
Airport
Citizens
City
Country
Finance
Language
Medical
Place of Interest
Visas
Other

Requiring classification of tags as well as questions may be excessive but something that enabled users to group these for themselves might be appreciated or even just a convenient means to download details might be useful.

For example, is there already a tag for Den Haag, and if so under D or T or H or elsewhere? And if not, what are the nearest alternatives that might serve adequately?

Indeed, does such a facility already exist?

Or is this mere [pie in the sky](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pie+in+the+sky)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stack Exchange founder Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) expressed a very strong dislike of any kind of tag hierarchy, e.g.

- [I don't think adding this kind of complexity would make the tag system better.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58073/implicit-tagging-hierarchy/61433#61433)
- [We do not support tag hierarchies.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72058/how-to-choose-good-tags-for-a-site/89931#89931)

I can't find a citation against a flat classification of tags, but no, that doesn't exist either. There's no significant proposal for that that I know of even on Stack Overflow, which has more [than 20 times as many tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) as we do.

I don't see the point in classifying tags anyway, except for a sociological or information science analysis. How would it help us for the day-to-day business of tagging and searching?