# Which tags and tag groups need attention (where several synonyms or the synonyms do not cover all they should)?

Tags: discussion, tagging

[Based on this question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3616/27650), I think are more tag groups that need attention.
I am thinking about public transport which does seem to include trams and buses but not trains, with high speed trains a separate tag again.

Adding and editing some tag info recently made me think there is a lot of tags made by rather new users which need attention.
(At only 300 points you can make a tag, which is very early in my view, but that is for a different question.)

If people mention tags and tag groups that need attention here, we can work on them. I am willing to help with those tags and tag groups I understand, but as a user on the level I am I can not do all.

Comment: Consider that tags attached to zero questions get burninated automatically after one month. In other words if a new user creates a random tag and you remove it from the question it's likely the tag won't stick around.

Comment: One of the problems with transportation is that there are multiple overlapping terms, with sometimes conflicting definitions, which a local person may use differently from an industry person. Consider recent comments here about whether Uber is a *taxi* (or what kind of taxi it is), or Wikipedia's squabbling over what to call the article currently at *limited-access road*, or the basic observations that the San Diego Trolley is not a trolley, and the Palm Springs Aerial Tramway is not a tram, and the Southern California Rapid Transit District never operated any rapid transit.

Answer (score 2):

> Which tags and tag groups need attention

Simply put, every single tag and hence also all tag "groups" (though we are not allowed to 'group' tags - see for example [“Tagging” tags (so to speak)](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/tagging-tags-so-to-speak)).

While ***I*** would very much appreciate any help with tagging, it is worth bearing in mind that many users do *not*, in practice (even if claiming to approve 'in theory').

We do presently have a Usage guide for every singe tag (almost) applied to any Open question - with something of an 'action plan' (see [September 2016 Tag Rename & Synonym MegaQuestion](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/september-2016-tag-rename-synonym-megaquestion)) for a few remaining 'special problem' tags.

Regarding specifically [public-transport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-transport) I have chosen to classify the following as 'sub-categories' (only for my own purposes):

[atac](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atac)
[london-underground](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/london-underground)
[oyster-card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oyster-card)
[ratp](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratp)
[tallinja-cards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tallinja-cards)
[tfl](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tfl)

(so nothing specifically about *modes* of travel) and regarding [trains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains):

[amtrak](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amtrak)
[china-railway](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-railway)
[deutsche-bahn](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deutsche-bahn)
[eurail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eurail)
[eurostar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eurostar)
[high-speed-rail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-speed-rail)
[indian-railways](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-railways)
[interrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interrail)
[japan-rail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan-rail)
[jr-passes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jr-passes)
[national-rail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/national-rail)
[nederlandse-spoorwegen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nederlandse-spoorwegen)
[shinkansen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shinkansen)
[sncf](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sncf)
[tatkal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tatkal)
[tgvair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tgvair)
[thalys](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thalys)
[the-canadian](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-canadian)
[train-stations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/train-stations)
[trans-siberian](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trans-siberian)
[trenitalia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trenitalia)
[trenord](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trenord)
[via-rail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/via-rail)

Regarding modes of transport I have sub-categorised [transportation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation) as below:

[ferries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ferries)
[airbus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus)
[aircraft](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft)
[air-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-travel)
[boeing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing)
[freighter-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freighter-travel)
[gondolas-and-cable-cars](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gondolas-and-cable-cars)
[helicopters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/helicopters)
[hitchhiking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitchhiking)
[intermodal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intermodal)
[night-transport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/night-transport)
[riverboats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riverboats)
[sea-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-travel)
[ships](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ships)
[submarine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/submarine)

There are various obvious tags missing from the above mostly because for them I chose to sub-categorise under the tag [road-trips](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/road-trips):

[automobiles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automobiles)
[avis](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avis)
[bikes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bikes)
[buses](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buses)
[car-pooling](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car-pooling)
[car-rentals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car-rentals)
[child-safety-seat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-safety-seat)
[driving](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/driving)
[driving-licenses](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/driving-licenses)
[greyhound](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greyhound)
[i-80](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i-80)
[marshrutkas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marshrutkas)
[motorcycles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorcycles)
[offroad](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offroad)
[ride-sharing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ride-sharing)
[road-signs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/road-signs)
[rvs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rvs)
[scooters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scooters)
[taxis](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxis)
[uber](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uber)
[vignettes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vignettes)

I will consider sub-categorsing [visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas) (presently I have 180 tags lumped together under that category) once the renaming/synonymising is up-to date. There are a further 140 or so tags that I have not (yet?) categorised at all. Note that the tag information from SEDE is only updated weekly and even on update lags the 'main' database by days even so.

I would suggest the priority is to address questions tagged [tagging](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) on meta. If the Community will not indicate its preferences then there is no hope of significant progress.